# .htaccess ssl redirect with rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I have been looking for a solution to this for quite some time, and banging my head against a brick wall.

The project I am working on uses Codeigniter. Currently my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|img|css|js|robots\.txt|.*\.htm|.*\.html|.*\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Which is all great, as I don't want to pass any of the files in my list of file extensions to index.php to be processed.

However, the client wants all traffic to have a 301 redirect to the https version of the site, so I set off on my travels around Google and SO and patched together a bunch of stuff I thought might work and came up with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|img|css|js|robots\.txt|.*\.htm|.*\.html|.*\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In my mind, this should have worked, as I understand it the first RewriteCond checks to see if https is off, then redirects the site to the https version of it. I thought that with the **R=301** flag it's a redirect, and the **L** flag stops the RewriteCond there and just forwards the site to https://www.example.com/, https://www.example.com/foo, whatever.

Then when we are at https://www.example.com the next rule sees that https is on, so it does its thing as normal.

**HOWEVER** I just get stuck in a redirection loop and I have absolutely no idea why. The site gets forwarded to https://www.example.com but then stops. I thought the L flags would end the rewrite stuff so that we wouldn't keep checking to see if we are in a loop?

Comment: I don't think so, but it can be the only reason I guess? It's driving me insane

Comment: It's telling me there's a loop of 301 redirects to https:// when I visit http and https

Comment: May be your Apache doesn't support `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`. What is your Apache version? You can also try: `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443`

Comment: Ah, yes that would make sense, it's working totally fine on my test server. Unfortunately ````RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443```` causes the same loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69911/discussion-between-ben-harvey-and-anubhava).